# Phonegap Installation on Windows 7

Tags: cordova, npm

I have already struggled with this for a few weeks. None of my searches helped install phonegap till the end. Here's what shows when I try to install it:

```
D:\USERS\haraujo>npm -g install phonegap
npm WARN engine ncallbacks@1.0.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.6.7"} (current: {"node":"0
.12.5","npm":"2.11.2"})
|


> cordova@2.7.4 install D:\USERS\haraujo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phoneg
ap\node_modules\cordova
> node bootstrap.js

shell.js: internal error
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'D:\USERS\haraujo\AppData\Roaming\npm\n
ode_modules\phonegap\node_modules\cordova\D:'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:747:18)
    at mkdirSyncRecursive (D:\USERS\haraujo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pho
negap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\shelljs\shell.js:1629:8)
    at mkdirSyncRecursive (D:\USERS\haraujo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pho
negap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\shelljs\shell.js:1634:3)
    at mkdirSyncRecursive (D:\USERS\haraujo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pho
negap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\shelljs\shell.js:1634:3)
    at mkdirSyncRecursive (D:\USERS\haraujo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pho
negap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\shelljs\shell.js:1634:3)
    at mkdirSyncRecursive (D:\USERS\haraujo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pho
negap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\shelljs\shell.js:1634:3)
    at mkdirSyncRecursive (D:\USERS\haraujo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pho
negap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\shelljs\shell.js:1634:3)
    at mkdirSyncRecursive (D:\USERS\haraujo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pho
negap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\shelljs\shell.js:1634:3)
    at mkdirSyncRecursive (D:\USERS\haraujo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pho
negap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\shelljs\shell.js:1634:3)
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "-g" "install" "phonegap"
npm ERR! node v0.12.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! cordova@2.7.4 install: `node bootstrap.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cordova@2.7.4 install script 'node bootstrap.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the cordova package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node bootstrap.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls cordova
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\USERS\haraujo\npm-debug.log
```

I need to install this to test hybrid development for mobile devices.

---

Update:

I managed, via Git, to clone phonegap-cli, cordova-cli, bootstrap and tried installing again without the -g flag. Got the following messages:

```
D:\USERS\haraujo>npm install phonegap-cli
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "phonegap-cli"
npm ERR! node v0.12.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=Parse Error
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\USERS\haraujo\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Have you added the JDK to your system path?

Comment: Just checked, it is in my system path (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote down all the things I did for my own PhoneGap installation (which was successful).

```
net use n: \\mycomputer\c$\some\really\long\path\Node.js\
c:
cd \users\Me\AppData\roaming\npm\bin
npm install -g phonegap
(manually had to fix failed native Microsoft projects since I have two Visual Studio installs)
n:
cd heroku
phonegap create MyAppName
```

Hope this helps.  Mapping a drive into a deep subdirectory structure sometimes helps given that Microsoft has a maximum path length of something like 260 characters or so.

UPDATE TO MATCH YOUR NEW ERROR:

Try instead:
 "npm install -g phonegap-cli"

Comment: Thanks Michael, after managing to clone phonegap-cli, cordova-cli and bootstrap via git, I now have a new error message ... will edit the original question updating the errmsg.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you're often restricted from writing to the Program Files area if you're a standard user.

Noting this part of the errors:

```
argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "-g" "install" "phonegap"
```

...it looks like it's trying to find node and npm somewhere there.

You might try starting a command prompt as Administrator and seeing if you may then install again that:  npm -g install phonegap.

Start -> type "cmd" in the search area and then right-mouse click Command Prompt and choose Run As Administrator

Comment: I was already running as admin. After I saw your answer I tried running that line "argv ..." from the command prompt (as admin, without the 'argv') and it showed me the same error message. I wish there was a way of installing it by downloading all the needed components in a local repository. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error.

Before issuing the 'npm install -g phonegap@latest' command, I changed my current directory to npm directory under node_modules and it worked. Please see below:

```
  set APPDATA=D:\mobile\appdata
  (my nodejs installed to D:\mobile\nodejs)
  (my npm installed to D:\mobile\nodejs\node_modules\npm)
  (So, moved my current directory as follows)
  cd D:\mobile\nodejs\node_modules\npm
  npm install -g phonegap@latest
```

Please let me know if it works for you.